# asp.net updatepanel checkboxlist attributes disappears

Tags: checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist inside an update panel. on postback the list is remember like I wanted.

The problem : 
When I fill the checkboxlist, I add custom attributes.

```
 cblItems.Items(1).Attributes.Add("id", "")
```

its working on the page load. But on the postback, my new attributes disappear.

I dont want to repopulate the list because the user could have check items and I want to remember checked value.

Do you know how to remember the attributes. Or maybe have a way to recreate the list and remember checked items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
            Recreate_attribute_cblItems()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Page Load verify if isn't a postback and try add the new attributes. Something like that:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!this.IsPostBack) {
       cblItems.Items(1).Attributes.Add("id", "");
    }
 }
```

Comment: In fact its the opposite. I needed to re-add on PostBask every attributes.